# Picklist values not showing on report

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type

I've checked the object/field security, my profile access, and record types of my Contact object and cannot figure out why when I run a report, there are no picklist values:

[image]

I'm able to SOQL the field and see Contact records do have values in the field. What else am I missing?